# SLES deployment failing with Input/output error

Tags: linux, suse, sles

I am getting the following error when i am trying to install and configure SLE 15 SP3 using [autoyast](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP3/html/SLES-all/book-autoyast.html) file.

```
 Caller: /mounts/mp_0001/usr/share/YaST2/lib/y2packager/repomd_downloader.rb:86:in 'read'
 Details: Input/output error @io_fread - /var/adm/mount/AP_OXYD6E14/Product-SLES/ repodata/repomd.xml
```

Could someone please help me with this? I just cant figure out the reason.

Comment: Please share your autoyast file or at least the respecitve section `<add-on>` (remove sensitive data). My guess would be that you reference a respository that this server can't reach during that stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `save_y2logs`, then analyze the file `YaST2/y2log`.
2. There might be an issue with the repositories or the syntax in your autoinst.xml file - for the former, confirm if they are mountable from an already installed system, for the latter, parse the file using `jing` on an installed SUSE system:

   ```
   jing /usr/share/YaST2/schema/autoyast/rng/profile.rng /path/to/autoinst.xml
   ```

Comment: used jing and xmllint both, autoinst.xml file was fine.
i am not sure how am i supposed to run save_y2logs. the installation failed and exited

Comment: You can switch to a virtual terminal using Ctrl + Alt + Fx (Fx being either of the F keys, I think F6 houses a console during the installation). The logbundle will then be saved and can be either inspected on the same machine or copied elsewhere.

Comment: oh ok, thanks. i will have a look.